# How to save a field added in the clean() method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My form has `first_name` and `last_name` fields, but my model has just a `name` field. In the `clean()` method of the form I set `self.cleaned_data['name']`, but when I try to save it I get this error:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

If I exclude it,

```
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    exclude = ('name',)
```

however, then it doesn't get saved.

So how do I get it to both save, and not throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
name = CharField(required=False)
```

To my form, but not displaying it on the page seems to work. I realized it was failing the first wave of validation before it even got to the `clean()` method, which is why it erroring. Just had to set `required=False`.